# What is the difference between `numpy.fix` and `numpy.trunc`?

Tags: python, numpy

Aside from the additional functionality that `trunc` possesses as a `ufunc`, is there any difference between these two functions? I expected `fix` to be defined using `trunc` as is fairly common throughout NumPy, but it is actually defined using `floor` and `ceil`.

If the `ufunc` functionality is the only difference, why does `fix` exist? (Or at least, why does `fix` not just wrap `trunc`?

Comment: You know the difference, having read the code.  Are you asking why it's different, or where it might give different values?  That's something you can explore just as well as the rest of us.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm asking if there are any input values for which the outputs differ, essentially.

Comment: I'm also curious as to the "why" of it all. I understand keeping a legacy function around for compatibility, but why isn't it deprecated like most of the others? I also really don't get why it has been implemented in this way. It `ceil`s every element, then overwrites elements that were greater than zero in the original array with the `floor` of those elements - that seems like a ton of wasted ops. Additionally, I've done some testing since posting this, and it seems `fix` is substantially less accurate with large floats.

Comment: Generally 'why' questions can only be answered by developers, and just a subset oof those,  The rest of us can only give opinions.  Sometimes you can find information on the github issues, or code history.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in the results.  Both functions, though implemented differently internally, produce the same results on the same set of input types and produce the same results in both value and type.  There is no good reason for having both functions, particularly when one will work more slowly and/or take more resources than the other and both must be maintained for as long as numpy survives.  Quite frankly, this is one problem with Python and many other design-by-committee projects, and you see debates over this trunc/fix issue in other language and library development projects like Julia.